# Sinch webRTC DevicesNotFoundError on Chrome Mozilla et al

Tags: webrtc, sinch

I am trying to setup up video calling in my webapp using Sinch. The application works well on my Chrome (50.0.2661.102 64 bit) but a friend using windows (same version chrome but 32 bit) gets a NavigatorUserMediaError with a reason : DevicesNotFoundError.

I tried using mozilla, vivaldi and IE but non of them works. The error is in the sinch.min.js file and I am using the latest version from their repository : https://cdn.sinch.com/latest/sinch.min.js

Can someone please help me fix these issues?
Also, are there any javascript libraries to help prevent cross-browser compatibility issues while using webRTC.

Thanks

Comment: why the downvote? its the correct answer

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. But haven't accepted it since Sinch is supposed to be working with these browsers at least FF and Chrome. The issue I mentioned was actually a bug. I raised a request with Sinch after posting this question and hopefully it works properly now. Maybe you can answer the second part (useful cross browser webRTC libraries, if any) and i will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only WebRTC browsers work with sinch

Answer (score 0):

The `NavigatorUserMediaError` error with err.name=`DevicesNotFoundError` is a Chrome specific error and it's quite common. It happens when:

- you’re requesting a video track through constraints but the user does not have a webcam
- you request an audio track but there is no attached recording device or it's disabled at the OS level (possible in Windows and some drivers do it automatically if there's no microphone inserted in the mic jack)

`DevicesNotFoundError` will be replaced by the spec compliant `NotFoundError` in Chrome 64.

Source: [Common getUserMedia() Errors](https://blog.addpipe.com/common-getusermedia-errors/)