# issue when trying to use webrtc in an ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc

I am trying to create an ionic app using webrtc (with the simplewebrtc lib). Everything is working fine on desktop browser but, when run on android (with crosswalk), the app throws an error of type: `localMediaError:NavigatorUserMediaError,DevicesNotFoundError`

Has anyone already experienced this kind of issue and has any clue on how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a little more information on your problem? Maybe share the relevant part of your code? Or tell us what Android version are you testing on?

Comment: You fill find the source code of the test app here: https://github.com/ramsestom/ionic-webrtc-test . My device run on android 5.1.1

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47549243/813988) which explains the `DevicesNotFoundError` error from Chrome.